# How to update HTML table cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Team,

Could you please tell me how to update a cell using jquery?

```
<table id='lop'>
    <thead id='loph'>
        <tr>
            <td class='type'>Type</td>
            <td class='name'>Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='lopb'>
        <tr id='1'>
            <td class='type'>W</td>
            <td class='name'>ZZZ</td> 
        <tr>
        <tr id='2'>
            <td class='type'>W</td>
            <td class='name'>YYY</td> 
        <tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to update second row name to XXX from YYY.
Please, The answer should be based on id and class name used in the html, not number/order based while using the jquery.

Also the below solution is not working,

```
$('#lop #2 .name').html('XXX')  //Working
```

in the case of

```
var rowID = '#2';
$('#lop rowID .name').html('XXX') //Not Working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, which is using the [html method](http://api.jquery.com/html) to update the code :

```
$('#lop #2 .name').html('XXX')
```

You can have a look to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cWQRY/

If you want to do it with a variable, you can try this code :

```
var rowID = '#2';
$('#lop '+rowID+' .name').html('XXX')
```

Comment: What is the benefit if i use .html than .text ??

Comment: In you case, there is no benefit. But with html method, you can edit the text and html code if there is.

Comment: Thanks!. Could you please also give me link for the syntax for $('#id1 #id2 .className), Is this only applicable to the table or can use it in some other dom structure.

Comment: Yes you can use it for some other dom structure.

Comment: This is not helping; in the case like; var rowId = '#2'; $('#lop rowId .name').html('XXX')

Comment: Help me in the above scenario.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do ? I don't understand. You said you want to change the content of a td. My code is working, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, It is working but in runtime i have to update the row(cell) value. So i have to pick the row accordingly by passed rowID.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you don't use integers as ids use string..

```
 <tr id='id2'>
```

why:

**1) It violates W3C specification.**

**2) It is detrimental to SEO.**

**3) There can be server-side scripting issues**

jquery

```
$('#id2 .name').text('XXX')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#2 .name).text('XXX');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#2 .name').html('XXX');
```

Check the js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xyn9e/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

* {
    font-family:Consolas
}

.editableTable {
    border:solid 1px;
    width:100%
}

.editableTable td {
    border:solid 1px;
}

.editableTable .cellEditing {
    padding: 0;
}

.editableTable .cellEditing input[type=text]{
    width:100%;
    border:0;
    background-color:rgb(255,253,210); 
}

Example: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425
```

Answer (score 0):

In Table using ID in each tr and td is not a good practice better you use index.

```
$('#lopb tr').filter(':eq(1) td.name').text('XXX');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#lop').each(function(){
                var $row = $(this).parents('tr');                  
                alert($row.find('td:eq(0)').html());
                alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify when you want to do this action of changing the cell data.

For changing, please try,

```
$('#2 .name').html('XXX')
```

Thanks
Manikandan